# What is the dif between Software testing and Software inspection?

Tags: testing, inspection

So I've read some reports about both of these methods but I can't really grasp the dif between the two.
If anyone could sum it up for me or try to explain it I'd be ever so grateful!
BR, Fredrik

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Similar to a car. If you test it, you usually drive it around or at least turn it on. If you inspect it usually you check fluids, maybe pull a spark plug, connect it to a computer and check its settings, fiddle with buttons and switches to make sure there is connectivity. During an inspection you may test the vehicle, but during a test you do not always inspect the vehicle.

Software testing is useful because it allows for a mock up of a production environment to be used in order to see if there are bugs, or errors which either throw exceptions or cause logical errors such as making relationships out of state.

Software inspection is more involved. It can involve testing, but can also involve doing code review to make sure that efficient process is used, and that the readability and maintainability is proper. It helps to make sure that features are properly decoupled, the program is running as fast as possible, and that nothing is going on behind the scenes which is undesirable.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer as it described it perfectly, I know have a better understanding of the two diffrence methods!

Comment: The reason I love stackoverflow is that people have so insightful examples.